# PHP exec forking a process, making it crash return code is still 0

Tags: php, linux

```
$cmd = "php thisWillCrash.php";
exec($cmd, $op, $return_code);
```

Then I check $return_code and its 0 indicating success, why is that?

I've tried several variations of "thisWillCrash.php" including

```
trigger_error("Fatal Error", E_USER_ERROR);
include("dasdasdsakdassadsad");
```

and a memory loop that will run out of memory, same result the return code is always 0. Any ideas?

Comment: $return_code is an array of the output returned from $cmd. FYI O is usually the opposite of success

Comment: @Dagon actually 0 is success with return codes. lookup true and false in binutils.

Comment: good call @programmerjake.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to get the script itself to explicitly exit with a status other than `0`

You could try some thing like:

```
<?php

try {
    throw new Exception;
} catch (Exception $exc) {
    exit(1);
}
```

Comment: wouldn't it be easier to just call `exit(1)`?

Comment: @programmerjake sure, I was just trying to illustrate how one might `exit(1)` when something went bad

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be no way to enforce a non-zero exit status from a valid php script, apart from calling `exit` explicitly. php's `main()` returns a non-zero only on:

- invalid command line (invalid argument, no such file etc)
- internal startup error
- specific mode error (e.g. lint mode)
- parse error
- php script called `exit`

So the simplest way to obtain a non-zero is something like `php nosuchfile.php`.